# How to cast a object get from reflection to DbSet<type>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I have a instance of DbContext, that have properties is the DbSet<"EntityName">. I have used the reflection to get all the instance of each DbSet<"EntityName">, but i can not use it, cause of i cant not cast it in to the DbSet<"EntityName">.

```cs
var types = _dbContext.GetType().GetProperty();
foreach(var type in types){
   var dbSetValue = type.GetValue(_dbContext, null);
   var entities = dbSetValue.ToList(); // error cause of i cant not cast it.
}
```

So in this case, i want to cast the `dbSetValue` to its type (DbSet..), The problem is the DbSet have the generic, that is can not cast. Is it posible?

Comment: What data type should `entities` be?

Comment: `entities ` should be a list of entity, like List<"EntityName">

Comment: You can't create a `List<"EntityName">`. The type of entity needs to be known at compile-time.

Comment: so, can i get list of this entity by the reflection?

Comment: have you tried to set dbSetValue as a dynamic? var replaces the type to object in this case but if you force the dynamic it should work

Comment: i tried, but it throw an exception.

Comment: ```dynamic dbSetValue = type.GetValue(_dbContext, null); var entities = dbSetValue.ToList();``` it throw an exception "'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet<BGC.K2.Data.Models.Contractor>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first I would suggest to check the PropertyType if it is really a DBSet.

Note that `type.GetValue(_dbContext)` returns an object, but you should handle the type as a `dynamic` during the reflection.

Since you need the dynamic to support the `IEnumerable` methods, you need to use an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.

Your code should look like this:

```
var types = _dbContext.GetType().GetProperties();

// Check if property is really a DbSet<TEntity>
var filteredTypes = types.Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsGenericType 
                                  && x.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>));

foreach (var type in filteredTypes)
{
     var dbSet = (IEnumerable<dynamic>) type.GetValue(_dbContext);    
     var entities = dbSet.ToList();
}
```

Comment: this is brillant.